# Failed assertion:'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null || items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) return item.value == value;}).length == 1'

Tags: flutter, dropdown

```
class DropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropDown({
    this.data,
    this.hint,
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final List<String> data;
  final String hint;
  @override
  _DropDownState createState() => _DropDownState();
}

String _chosenValue1;

class _DropDownState extends State<DropDown> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        width: 250,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          iconSize: 30,
          isExpanded: true,
          value: _chosenValue1,

          //elevation: 5,
          items: widget.data.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
          hint: Text(
            widget.hint,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 13,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
          ),
          onChanged: (String value) {
            setState(() {
              _chosenValue1 = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
   DropDown(
                        data: [
                          'Non-Blanchable',
                          'Partial thickness skin',
                          'Full thickness skin loss involving damage or necrosis',
                          'Obscured by necrosis'
                        ],
                        hint: 'Assessment',
                      ),
  DropDown(
                        data: [
                          'Indistinct, diffuse,none ',
                          'Distinct,outline clearly'
                        ],
                        hint: 'Assessment',
                      ),
```

i have been stuck on this problem for a while now, When i have the same data inside the data it works however all the dropdown would become the same, I want to be able to have different data for different dropdown , but when i do so the error is caused and i cant figure out whats wrong with it

Answer (score 1):

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  DropDown({
    this.data,
    this.hint,
    this.initialValue,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final List<String>? data;
  final String? hint;
  final String? initialValue;
  String chosenValue1 = "";

  @override
  _DropDownState createState() => _DropDownState();
}

class _DropDownState extends State<DropDown> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        width: 250,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          iconSize: 30,
          isExpanded: true,
          value: widget.initialValue!.isEmpty ? null : widget.initialValue!,

          //elevation: 5,
          items: widget.data!.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
          hint: Text(
            widget.hint!,
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 13,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
          ),
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              widget.chosenValue1 = value!;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dropdown.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            DropDown(
              data: const [
                'Non-Blanchable',
                'Partial thickness skin',
                'Full thickness skin loss involving damage or necrosis',
                'Obscured by necrosis'
              ],
              hint: 'Assessment',
              initialValue: "Non-Blanchable",
            ),
            DropDown(
              data: const [
                'Indistinct, diffuse,none',
                'Distinct,outline clearly'
              ],
              hint: 'Assessment',
              initialValue: "",
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Use the above code it will fix ur error

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code and, after making your `data` and `hint` required params and moving the `chosenValue` variable inside your `_DropDownState`, it works perfectly fine. Can you maybe share some steps with how to reproduce the error that you're seeing, because I see two different dropdowns with values I can select independently of each other.

As per your description of how to reproduce the error, I've tried adding navigation between two screens, but it still all works as intended.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Dropdowns(),
    );
  }
}

class Dropdowns extends StatelessWidget {
  const Dropdowns();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('This is the first screen'),
            DropDown(
              data: [
                'Non-Blanchable',
                'Partial thickness skin',
                'Full thickness skin loss involving damage or necrosis',
                'Obscured by necrosis'
              ],
              hint: 'Assessment',
            ),
            DropDown(
              data: ['Indistinct, diffuse,none ', 'Distinct,outline clearly'],
              hint: 'Assessment',
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Go to second screen'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => SecondScreen(),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropDown({
    required this.data,
    required this.hint,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final List<String> data;
  final String hint;
  @override
  _DropDownState createState() => _DropDownState();
}

class _DropDownState extends State<DropDown> {
  String? _chosenValue1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        width: 250,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          iconSize: 30,
          isExpanded: true,
          value: _chosenValue1,

          //elevation: 5,
          items: widget.data.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
          hint: Text(
            widget.hint,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 13,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
          ),
          onChanged: (String? value) {
            setState(() {
              _chosenValue1 = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('SECOND SCREEN'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('This is the second screen'),
            DropDown(
              data: [
                'Non-Blanchable',
                'Partial thickness skin',
                'Full thickness skin loss involving damage or necrosis',
                'Obscured by necrosis'
              ],
              hint: 'Assessment',
            ),
            DropDown(
              data: ['Indistinct, diffuse,none ', 'Distinct,outline clearly'],
              hint: 'Assessment',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Im using sdk 2.10.0 , so having to add the required is fine, its when i exit the page and reenter the screen it doesnt work for me the error appears if your understand what im saying, it works normally when you select your item in the dropdown but once you go to the next screen and go back it causes an error. i hope you understand if not im sorry i cant explain it better i dont understand how the error is being caused

Comment: I'll try to reproduce the error, thank you, I'll get back to you in a bit.

Comment: Or another way it causes the error is when you select your dropdown and you want to go to another screen with another dropdown the error occurs. Again i really dont understand how to explain the error :(

Comment: Can you check my edit? I've added navigation to a second screen with also two dropdowns, but it all still works. You can go to the second screen and make a selection, pop back to the first and it still remembers your initial selection, all without breaking. Did you also remember to add _chosenValue1 to be inside your class, instead of outside of it as a global variable. I can imagine that breaks things.

Answer (score 0):

```
                      onChanged: (String value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _chosenValue = value;
                          selcat = null; use dropdown as category
                          
             _chosenValue == null

                      ? Container()
                      : _chosenValue == "hi"
                          ? _hi()
                          : _chosenValue == "hello"
                              ? _hello()
                              : Container(),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).